# Search text box in iOS is case sensitive

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a text box in iOS in which a user can enter a name and retrieve the users with that name. I use the parse query below for this. Actually it works fine, but it is case sensitive.

For example when the user's name is "Martin" in parse table, and you enter "Martin" to text box, it finds it, but when you enter "martin" it doesn't find anything. Is there a way to use the "containString" not case sensitive?

```
var query = PFUser.query()
query!.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
query!.whereKey("profileName", containsString: self.userSearchField.text)
```

Edit:

I found another solution, I created a new column in my databse called "searchUser" and when a person signs up with a new user name a few versions of the user name are stored in that column (for example, all letters capital, all letters lowercase, only first letters lowercase). And use the "containsString" in that column. Now it has a higher possiblity to find that user. Something like below:

```
    var varSearch1 = profileTxt.text
    var varSearch2 = profileTxt.text.lowercaseString
    var varSearch3 = profileTxt.text.uppercaseString
    var varSearch4 = profileTxt.text.capitalizedString

    user["searchUser"] = "\(varSearch1) \(varSearch2) \(varSearch3) \(varSearch4)"
```

Answer (score 1):

As **Hector Ramos** (Parser) says in [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/case-insensitive-pfquery) post:

> You'd need to query for the users and use localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: locally. Using orderByAscending: will, as you have already found out, order the results alphabetically.

Because the case-insensitive query is very expensive. If you have few users, it's a feasible solution, but as one person points out in the discussion - loading 20k users is simply not great.

If you can use canonical field for it, it would surely make things easier for you.